# How To Install C# to Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate

Tags: c#, download

When I installed Visual Studio 2012, I didn't choose C# and only chose VB.NET , Now I need C# to develop ASP.NET MVC 4 project. How do I add C#? I can't reinstall Visual Studio. Any fast method?

[image]

Comment: You use the same setup program used to install this version to change your current installation. You should find it in your Installed Programs folder in Win10 settings. What do you mean _I can't reinstall Visual Studio_?

Comment: Thanks man, already figured it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just had to reset Visual Studio, and I could've just changed the installation by going to Control Panel, Add or Remove Programs, Visual Studio..

Answer (score 0):

It seems that You Cannot Select Windows in the right side.. 
You select Web ... That way u cannot find C# Windows form Application.

[Here is Screen Shoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/us7Wr.png)